# ActionSheet Actions in Swift

Tags: ios, mobile, swift

I am new to swift and IOS development in general so I am made an Action Sheet in Xcode, but now I want to perform actions from the Action Sheet. I am familiar with doing this in ObjC by using a button Index, but I can not seem to figure this out in swift.

I would also like to customize my Action sheet to make the text different colors, but that is not as important. Please let me know if you can help. Thanks

Here is my code so far but I the .tag part of the Action when the button is pressed is wrong...

```
    @IBAction func ActionSheet(sender: UIButton) {

    var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet();
    let title: String = "Action Sheet!";
    sheet.title  = title;
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel");
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("A course");
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("B course");
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("C course");
    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
    sheet.showInView(self.view);

}


func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if (actionSheet.tag == 1) {
        NameLabel.text = "I am confused"

    }
}
```

Comment: So, Were u able to resolve it ?

Comment: not yet but I am hoping to soon

Comment: I figured it out... I was just forgetting 2 lines of code

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Make your view controller conform to the `UIActionSheetDelegate` protocol:

   `class ViewController: UIViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate {`
2. Add `self` as the delegate, and set the tag to 1:

   ```
   var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
   let title: String = "Action Sheet!"
   sheet.title  = title
   sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
   sheet.addButtonWithTitle("A course")
   sheet.addButtonWithTitle("B course")
   sheet.addButtonWithTitle("C course")
   sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
   sheet.delegate = self                  // new line here
   sheet.tag = 1                          // another new line here
   sheet.showInView(self.view)
   ```
3. Now you can use the `buttonIndex`:

---

```
func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if sheet.tag == 1 {
        println(buttonIndex)
        println(sheet.buttonTitleAtIndex(buttonIndex))
    }
}
```

Comment: He has to make sure his actionSheet's tag is actually 1 as well (it's not set based on his code).

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of the tag in my version of the code, but not the version I posted.

Comment: This is still not working for me even after I included UIActinoSheetDelegate... It has an error that says this: '(UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex:Int) -> ()' does not have a member named 'tag'. Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: See the edits.  You need to check `if sheet.tag == 1` not `if actionSheet.tag == 1.  Also, you need to set the tag to one when you create the actionSheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sequence is not correct, also the delegate is not set.

Declare Your class as delegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate{
```

...

Define Action Sheet

```
  @IBAction func ActionSheet(sender: UIButton) {

    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "ActionSheet", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: "Done", otherButtonTitles: "A Course", "B Course", "C course")
    actionSheet.showInView(self.view)

}
```

Define Delegate Function

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    switch buttonIndex{

    case 0:
        NSLog("Done");
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog("Cancel");
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog("A Course");
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog("B Course");
        break;
    case 4:
        NSLog("C Course");
        break;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a library that you can make it work like an action sheet view :)

https://github.com/srujanadicharla/SASelectionView